# TSQL how to assign number to the group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wish to find /assign consecutive number for groups in my data.

That `<Group Number>` column like in the desired output picture. I just need to add 2 new columns. `Group Number` is number per `GroupID` per each ID. Tried all Rank/Row_Numb/Dense could not figure out, I also need `< Rank by ID,GroupID>` but it's done with `row_number`.

Do I need to do any running values? I'm on SQL Server 2019.

Sample code is here:

```
/*
SELECT * INTO #t FROM (    --- sample data load   select * from #t            ----   drop table #t
SELECT '1234' ID, 'American 1' Risk_Name,  1 line, 10 GroupID   UNION
SELECT '1234', 'Asian 21', 2, 20  UNION SELECT '1234', 'Asian 24', 3, 20 UNION SELECT '1234', 'Asian 28', 4, 20  union
SELECT '1234', 'Europe 300', 5,30  UNION SELECT '1234', 'Europe 388', 6,  30   union
SELECT '88888', 'American 2', 1, 10 UNION SELECT '88888', 'American 4', 2, 10   UNION SELECT '88888', 'Europe 33', 3,30 )a
*/

SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, GROUPID ORDER BY line) RankByID_GroupID
    -- ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY  GROUPID, ID  ORDER BY line) GroupNumber--????
FROM 
    #t

ID      Risk_Name   line    GroupID
------------------------------------
1234    American 1  1       10
1234    Asian 21    2       20
1234    Asian 24    3       20
1234    Asian 28    4       20
1234    Europe 300  5       30
1234    Europe 388  6       30
88888   American 2  1       10
88888   American 4  2       10
88888   Europe 33   3       30
```

And this is desired output:

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY GROUPID`.

```
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, GROUPID ORDER BY line) AS RankByID_GroupID,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY GROUPID) AS GroupNumber
FROM #t;
```

Comment: Early morning magic from Amit, Thanks much !!!

Comment: Or evening - depending on what side of the world they are on :)

Comment: And consider whether you might accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Thanks Amit and all again, finally found that V-)